# InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "fallbacks" under "framework.translator"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have used Symfony '2.3.*' version in my project. after updating the composer. I am getting following error and not able to fix the issues.
Error is:

> InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "fallbacks" under "framework.translator"

Kindly Help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the difference that was introduced in `2.3.25`:

> New in version 2.3.25: The **fallbacks** option was introduced in Symfony 2.3.25. Prior to Symfony 2.3.25, it was called **fallback** and only allowed one fallback language defined as a string. Please note that you can still use the old fallback option if you want define only one fallback.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/framework.html#translator

Does this help?